# QnA Maker unable to select "tenant"

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

After following the new instructions to [create a QnA bot service in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/how-to/set-up-qnamaker-service-azure), the next step is to login to [QnA Maker and create a KB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/quickstarts/create-publish-knowledge-base).

I login to QnA Maker, skip the "Create a QnA Service" step (because I already completed it) but the "Microsoft Azure Directory ID" dropdown is blank.

[image]

So far I've tried:

- Refreshing the page
- Deleting the bot service I created and create it from the QnA Maker KB Step 1
- Deleting all bot services and starting over

Getting annoyed here. What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the same thing happened with me but it got solved just by logout and login again in the qnamaker portal site. Also you should have same login id for qnamaker and the azure portal where you will create the QnAMaker service.
Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you. Signing in / out worked. (silly! I should have tried that before posting!)